# How do I call a function with parameters in MainActivity from non-dynamic receiver?

Tags: java, android, function, broadcastreceiver

In my MainActivity, I have the following function:

```
public void writefile (FileOutputStream fOut, String fileName, OutputStreamWriter osw, String message){
    try {
        fOut = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(message);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My SMS receiver for this app MUST be non-dynamic (no layout), and within my onReceive method, I try to call the function:

```
writefile(fOut, ib1, osw, message);
```

My parameters are all ok, but 'writefile' becomes red and 'cannot be resolved.'  So I tried changing it to:

```
MainActivity.writefile(fOut, ib1, osw, message);
```

But now, 'writefile' is underlined with a static/non-static problem.  In order to get rid of this error, I tried making the function static in MainActivity, but then, 'openFileOutput' starts to complain about static/non-static.

I was willing to put the function into my Receiver class too to be called every time from the same class, but functions like 'openFileOutput' cannot be resolved because the Receiver can only extend BroadcastReceiver.

I was also willing to call another activity upon onReceiver and do my work there, but I couldn't find a way to implement that either.

Can anybody please offer me any help on this issue?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFileOutput()` is a method on `Context`. Your activity is a `Context`, and your receiver gets a `Context` passed to it in `onReceive()`. So, make the `writefile()` method `static`, and pass in a `Context` as a parameter. Then, call `openFileOutput()` on the passed-in `Context`. Your activity can use the `static` method by passing in `this` for the `Context`. Your receiver can use the `static` method by passing in the `Context` you get in `onReceive()`.

Then, make sure that you are only calling `writefile()` on a background thread.